# Overflow:hidden does not work in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I am stuck with a problem, I don't understand: my method to make YouTube images round is to put them in a container with

```
border-radius: 50%; 
overflow: hidden;
```

This works on Chrome and FF, but Safari places the image "over" the round container.

Please check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikita_turing/2QyY3/

How do I make the images round on Safari?

Comment: Works for me on Safari 6.0.2

Comment: Mine was 5.1.7 on windwos and the version on my ipod touch (ios 5.0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in Safari 5.1.7 (PC) the `position:relative` on the image seems to prevent the `border-radius` from being applied

remove `position:relative` and set `margin-left` (instead of `left`) in your jQuery then it works

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2QyY3/2/)

Comment: Well thanks a lot - you solved it. But here's the next question for you: why is the border doing strange in safari? http://jsfiddle.net/nikita_turing/2QyY3/3/

Comment: appears to be a documented [webkit bug (#72619)](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619) (with at least [3 dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Awebkit.org+position+relative+border-radius)) and was resolved recently.  Since Safari 5.1.7 came out [May 2012](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531) it doesn't have the fix.

Comment: Aug/2014 and still broken. This is ridiculous

Comment: @DanielGuerra broken in Safari 5.1.7 (PC) I assume?...Apple support has dried up for Safari on PC.

Comment: @leosok: Because Safari is the new IE.