# Overflow Hidden on Video Element in Safari

Tags: css, html, safari

I have a video element that I want to hide inside a div with `border-radius: 50%;`
This works fine and dandy on Chrome and Firefox, but not on Safari.

The gist of my css is this:

```
.back{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 50%; 
}

.back video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 267px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be safari bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077696/overflowhidden-does-not-work-in-safari

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I initially had the same issue with GIFs, but was able to solve it by using `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0);` on the parent. However I've had to change the markup to use `video` elements and it doesn't seem to respect `overflow: hidden` even with the transform (and only an issue in Safari).

Answer (score 10):

I tried what @indextwo recommended in his comment, and it worked!

Just add this to the parent of the `<video>` element:

```
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This absolutely works. Blew my mind. Why would this work.