# Overflow is not working in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

overflow is not working in Safari. Please help.

In circles, overflow is appering but in other browser it is hidden due to overflow but in safari it is not hidden.

http://realestate.fssdemo.com/services/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077696

Answer (score 0):

check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubhambhave/ckV88/)

remove the style

```
position: relative
```

And adjust margin

Answer (score 0):

```
Overflow hidden css effect worked for all browsers example[***enter image description here***][1]

    <!-- HTML -->
<div class="menu-categories w-100">
<ul class="p-0">
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="furniture.jpg" alt="Furniture" title="Furniture"> <span>
<label>
Furniture              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="coffee.jpg" alt="Breakroom" title="Breakroom"> <span>
<label>
Breakroom              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="janitorial-sanitation.jpg" alt="Cleaning<br> Supplies" title="Cleaning<br> Supplies"> <span>
<label>
Cleaning<br> Supplies              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="office-supplies.jpg" alt="Office<br>Supplies" title="Office<br>Supplies"> <span>
<label>
Office<br>Supplies              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="technology.jpg" alt="Technology" title="Technology"> <span>
<label>
Technology              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="outer_wrap">
<div class="inner_wrap position-relative"> <a href="#"> <img src="inkToner.png" alt="Ink &amp; Toner Finder" title="Ink &amp; Toner Finder"> <span>
<label>
Ink &amp; Toner Finder              </label>
</span> </a> </div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

.menu-categories ul li div.inner_wrap:hover,.outer_wrap .inner_wrap{-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-mask-image:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle,#fff 100%,#000 100%)}.menu-categories ul{width:100%;list-style:none}.menu-categories ul li{display:inline-block;width:200px;margin:15px 7px;height:200px}.menu-categories ul li div.outer_wrap{width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;padding:0}.outer_wrap .inner_wrap{width:90%;height:90%;padding:5%;border:1px solid #ccc;cursor:pointer;border-radius:50%;-moz-border-radius:50%;-webkit-border-radius:50%;overflow:hidden}.menu-categories ul li div img{width:auto;height:auto;max-width:70%;padding:15%;-webkit-transition:all .4s linear;-moz-transition:all .4s linear;-o-transition:all .4s linear;transition:all .4s linear}.menu-categories ul li div span{position:absolute;bottom:0;width:100%;left:0;right:0;height:50px;background:rgba(0,0,0,.7);color:#fff;font-size:16px;line-height:inherit;display:table}.menu-categories ul li div label{display:table-cell;height:50px;line-height:inherit;vertical-align:middle;padding:0 20%}.menu-categories ul li div.inner_wrap:hover{border:1px solid #003664;-webkit-transition:all 250ms ease-out 50ms;-moz-transition:all 250ms ease-out 50ms;-o-transition:all 250ms ease-out 50ms;transition:all 250ms ease-out 50ms}.menu-categories ul li div:hover span{background:rgba(0,54,100,.7)}.menu-categories ul li div:hover img{-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);transform:scale(1.1)}.menu-categories ul li div.janitorial span{line-height:20px}:root .menu-categories ul li div span,_::-moz-svg-foreign-content{left:inherit;right:inherit;width:100%}*|html[xmlns*=""] .menu-categories ul li div span{left:inherit;right:inherit;width:100%}
```

It will works fine in all browsers, try it
for live Demo [enter link description here](https://www.officemart.com/)